# Parsing value into nullable enumeration

Tags: c#, enums, nullable

Let's say I have this:

```
PriorityType? priority;
string userInput = ...;
```

I cannot change how this is defined: `PriorityType? priority` because it's actually part of a contract with another piece of code.

I tried this, but it does not work:

```
if (Enum.TryParse<PriorityType?>(userInput, out priority)) {
```

What is the correct way?

Comment: You can't create a temporary `PriorityType` and then assign it to `priority` after you parse it?

Comment: Yeah, I can, just thought there was maybe a better way. Post this as an answer and if there's not a better way, then I'll accept yours. :)

Comment: I don't think there is. The `TEnum` generic parameter is setup as `where TEnum: struct`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way:

```
PriorityType tempPriority;
PriorityType? priority;

if (Enum.TryParse<PriorityType>(userInput, out tempPriority))
    priority = tempPriority;
```

This is the best I can come up with:

```
public static class NullableEnum
{
    public static bool TryParse<T>(string value, out T? result) where T :struct, IConvertible
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
            throw new Exception("This method is only for Enums");

        T tempResult = default(T);

        if (Enum.TryParse<T>(value, out tempResult))
        {
            result = tempResult;
            return true;
        }

        result = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Use:

```
if (NullableEnum.TryParse<PriorityType>(userInput, out priority))
```

The above class can be used just like `Enum.TryParse` except with a nullable input. You could add another overloaded function that takes a non-nullable `T` so that you could use it in both instances if you want. Unfortunately extension methods don't work very well on enum types (as far as I could try to manipulate it in the short time I tried).

Answer (score 20):

If you want it to be a single line of code, you can do it like this:

```
var priority = Enum.TryParse<PriorityType>(userInput, out var outPriority) ? outPriority : (PriorityType?) null;
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the [same solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33311401/4298200) posted by [Ron Beyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4798077/ron-beyer) with a little refactoring:

```
 public static class NullableEnum
{
    public static bool TryParse<T>(string value, out T? result) where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Enum");

        result = Enum.TryParse(value, out T tempResult) ? tempResult : default(T?);

        return (result == null) ? false : true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works nicely but I'm wondering why it doesn't work if you just use `default` (`vs default(T?)`).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach here that actually lets you handle the nullable enums rather than failing when you get them:

```
public static class EnumHelper {

    public static TEnum Parse<TEnum>( string value ){
        if( typeof(TEnum).IsEnum )
            return (TEnum)Enum.Parse( typeof(TEnum), value );

        Type? nullableType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType( typeof(TEnum) );
        if( /*not a nullable type*/nullableType is null )
            throw new ArgumentException( $"Provided type {typeof(TEnum).Name} must be either an enum or a nullable enum" );

        return (TEnum?)Enum.Parse( nullableType, value );
    }

}
```

Call pattern is slightly different than the base lib that uses the `out` param, but can wrap it in the same call pattern if you like. Above for most cases tends to be easier to work with.